# Perform mutate function only if variable exists

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a function that applies specific functions to multiple columns in a data frame. Each of these functions are unique and can only be applied to that column.

```
convert_columns <- function(df) {
    df %>% mutate(
        a = convert_a(a),
        b = convert_b(b),
        c = convert_c(c),
        d = convert_d(d),
        e = convert_e(e)
        )
}
```

However, it is possible that users may input a data frame that only have a subset of those columns (for example, only `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like the function to `mutate` column `a`, `b`, and `c` if those columns exist in the inputted data frame and ignore columns `d` and `e`.

I have tried

```
convert_columns <- function(df) {
    df %>% mutate(across(any of(),
        a = convert_a(a),
        b = convert_b(b),
        c = convert_c(c),
        d = convert_d(d),
        e = convert_e(e)
        ))
}
```

and

```
convert_columns <- function(df) {
    df %>% mutate(across(any of(
        a = convert_a(a),
        b = convert_b(b),
        c = convert_c(c),
        d = convert_d(d),
        e = convert_e(e)
        )))
}
```

These do not work. Is there a simple way in the `tidyverse` syntax to accomplish what I am trying to do? In my actual use case, I have ~150 columns I will be mutating.

Comment: Are you really applying a different function to each column?

Comment: Yes, they all have to be processed individually in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since functions are unique to each variable and you want to return remaining values if one of the columns fail can't really come up with better solution than to use `tryCatch` on individual columns.

```
library(dplyr)

convert_columns <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(
    a = tryCatch(convert_a(a),error = function(z) return(NA)),
    b = tryCatch(convert_b(b),error = function(z) return(NA)),
    c = tryCatch(convert_c(c),error = function(z) return(NA)),
    #...
    #...
    )
}
```

---

This can be tested using the following `mtcars` example :

This works -

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(a = n_distinct(cyl), 
         b = mean(mpg), 
         c = sd(am))
```

Now if we remove one of the column, the above fails :

```
mtcars %>%
  select(-am) %>%
  mutate(a = n_distinct(cyl), 
         b = mean(mpg), 
         c = sd(am))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `c`.
> x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
> ℹ Input `c` is `sd(am)`.

Now using `tryCatch`

```
mtcars %>%
  select(-am) %>%
  mutate(a = tryCatch(n_distinct(cyl), error = function(e) return(NA)), 
         b = tryCatch(mean(mpg), error = function(e) return(NA)), 
         c = tryCatch(sd(am), error = function(e) return(NA)))

#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs gear carb a  b  c
#1   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.6   16  0    4    4 3 20 NA
#2   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.9   17  0    4    4 3 20 NA
#3   23   4  108  93  3.9 2.3   19  1    4    1 3 20 NA
#4   21   6  258 110  3.1 3.2   19  1    3    1 3 20 NA
#....
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I ended up doing. It seemed much simpler than other solutions, was rapid to implement in my existing code base, and in addition, I could pass multiple arguments to each of the individual functions. To be fair, I neglected to mention that not all of the functions I needed to perform required only one argument.

Comment: It does seem like a potential hack in that I will miss any legitimate errors that are being thrown from these functions.

Comment: Yes, the thing is this will return `NA` for any error. You could explore object `e` in `error` part and maybe capture only specific error which might arise because variable not found.

Comment: Sorry, I had to unaccept this answer. In practice, it does not actually do as expected and I just realized I could have caught this slightly earlier in your example. Your example still produces a column `c`. My use case requires that if `c` did not already exist in the inputted data frame, then I do not want that column to be created.

Comment: @DylanRussell Instead of `NA`, you can return `NULL` and the new column is not created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch()` to get a specific function based on column name. For instance, here, columns a, b, and c are either added, subtracted, or multiplied together, based on column name. We have to use `dplyr::cur_column()` to get the column name within across (`deparse(substitute())` just returns `"col"`).

Thus, with the below method, you can supply just a single function to `across()` but apply specific function to each column, while getting benefits of `any_of()`

```r
library(dplyr)

ex <- function(x) {
  arg <- cur_column()
  fn <- switch(arg,
               a = `+`,
               b = `-`,
               c = `*`)
  fn(x, x)
}

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2),
                 b = c(3,4))

mutate(df, across(any_of(c("a", "b", "c")), ex))
#>   a b
#> 1 2 0
#> 2 4 0
```

Comment: I like that this solution uses dplyr but I am not able to figure out how to pass one or more arguments to the functions in backticks. Not every function in `fn` is of the form `fn(x,x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
existing_cols <- c("a", "b", "c", "d") %>% intersect(names(df))
setDT(df)
if(length(existing_cols) > 0)
  df[, 
    (existing_cols) := map2(.SD, str_c("convert_", existing_cols), ~do.call(.y, list(.x))), 
    .SDcols = existing_cols
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward in base R.  There must be some way to associate the functions with column names so let us assume we have a named vector of functions or function names, `funs`.  Then loop through the data frame columns looking up the column name in `funs` applying the corresponding function to each column.

The first argument of `convert_coiumns` is the data frame, the second argument is the named vector of functions (or function names) and the third argument is a character vector of columns to convert.  The last argument defaults to all columns for which there is a function in `funs`.  The default for the last argument could be simplified to `names(data)` if it is always the case that every column must have a corresponding function.

Internally `match.fun` takes a function or function name, i.e. character string, and returns the function in each case allowing funs to contain functions, function names or a mix.

```
convert_columns <- function(data, funs, 
     nms = intersect(names(data), names(funs))) {
  for(nm in nms) data[[nm]] <- match.fun(funs[[nm]])(data[[nm]])
  data
}

# example 1 - uses built in BOD data frame
funs <- c(Time = sqrt, demand = mean)
convert_columns(BOD, funs)

# example 2 - same but use function names rather than functions themselves
funs2 <- c(Time = "sqrt", demand = "mean")
convert_columns(BOD, funs2)

# example 3 - DF does not have column b
funs3 <- c(a = sqrt, b = sum, c = mean)
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:3, c = 3:1)
convert_columns(DF, funs3)

# example 4 - grab functions from global environment - same DF
convert_a <- sum; convert_b <- prod; convert_c <- sqrt
funs4 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^convert_"))
names(funs4) <- sub("convert_", "", names(funs4)) # remove convert_ from names
convert_columns(DF, funs4)

# example 5 - similar to 4
funs5 <- setNames(paste("convert", names(DF), sep = "_"), names(DF))
convert_columns(DF, funs5)
```

Comment: Is there any way to implement this code but be able to pass one or more arguments to the functions in  `funs`?

Comment: Using `convert_columns` shown in the answer then if we have 
`f <- function(x, a) x + a` and want to apply it to the Time column with a = 1 then:
`funs <- list(Time = function(x) f(x, 1)); convert_columns(BOD, funs)`